# Codeigniter - change url at method call

Tags: codeigniter, url, post, edit

I was wondering if the following can be done in codeigniter.

Let's assume I have a file, called Post.php, used to manage posts in an admin interface.
It has several methods, such as index (lists all posts), add, update, delete...
Now, I access the add method, so that the url becomes

/posts/add

And I add some data. I click "save" to add the new post. It calls the same method with an if statement like "if "this->input->post('addnew')"" is passed, call the model, add it to the database

Here follows the problem:
If everything worked fine, it goes to the index with the list of all posts, and displays a confirmation

BUT

No the url would still be posts/add, since I called the function like $this->index() after verifying data was added. I cannot redirect it to "posts/" since in that case no confirmation message would be shown!

So my question is: can i call a method from anther one in the same class, and have the url set to that method (/posts/index instead of /posts/add)?

It's kinda confusing, but i hope i gave you enough info to spot the problem

Cheers!

Comment: You can add for example ?message=successful-added to the index method and display based upon that a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `redirect()` in conjunction with CodeIgniter's [Flash Data](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), or opt for AJAX.

Comment: Flashdata! yeah, I should have thought about it! Thanks so much!